# Linking Not working

Tags: php, html

I am so confused what's the difference between those links below:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/demo/assets/css/style.css"`

and

`<li> <a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/demo/contents/test.php"> HOME </a> </li>`

First of all, the first link is working very well, but the second link is not working. As it is written *The requested URL /demo/contents/test.php was not found on this server.*

My directory files is public_html > demo > contents > test.php. Any ideas?

Comment: use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] except $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Comment: Because for including php files you need to use include() or require() functions and provide the absolute path of the file in the functions as a parameter and not the url.

Above files are css files and they can be loaded by url thats why its working

Comment: @fiction If he will use your suggestion still there will be http:// at the beginning and there will be the same error

Comment: @Veerendra so remove http:// and use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].

Comment: @Veerendra ya, DOCUMENT_ROOT also not working because my files are not the very first start folder.

Comment: @fiction I did and it still doesn't work. Like this? `<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>/demo/contents/test.php?>` ?

Comment: @fiction why are you using echo it will just display the  file and path on the browser. If you want to include the file as you have done with css you need to use the function include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/demo/contents/test.php');

Comment: @Veerendra like this? `<li><a href="<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/demo/contents/test.php'); ?>"> HOME </a></li>` ? Can you put on the answer below?

Comment: I didn't get why are you writing it inside anchor tag.
What actually you want to achieve with that php file. please explain so i can post answer

Comment: @Veerendra Actually I want to click the link to its page. Not to get the files. It doesn't work as the files cannot be found. But the directory files are exactly there.

Comment: Can't you use relative links ? Like `href="/demo/contents/test.php"` ?

Comment: @Brewal I wish I can, but all the files I have included header. So the navigation links are in header. So I have to put `<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/`.

Comment: @smallcaterpillar by starting your links with a `/`, they will always refer to the root of your website.

Comment: Look, I have two files in two different folders, and two of them has including `header.php` on the root folder. Even I use `\` also not working because one is working and another one is not working. @Brewal

Comment: Please provide the outputed links (php result) and the URL you consult your website (could be localhost, doesn't matters)

Comment: @Brewal Could you tell me how to outputed the links? :/

Comment: That is what you see in the html under your browser with ctrl+u under chrome and FF

Comment: Nah when I checked, 404 Not Found. I am wondering what's wrong? The files are exactly there.

Comment: What URL are you typing in your browser to see your website ?

Comment: @Brewal It is `<li><a href="/demo/contents/test.php"> HOME </a></li>`. Exactly the same without `http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/`. If I put that HTTP_HOST, it will show like this `<li><a href="mywebsite.com/demo/contents/test.php"> HOME </a></li>`.

Comment: I suggest you post a short, self-contained, compilable example.  That is, give us an example.php, and any other files we must have to run it.  Shorten it so there's nothing that doesn't relate to the problem.  Shorten the URL's used so everything can go in the same folder.  Then we can take your code, run it ourselves, and see how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Its best to use

> $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Then access the folder from the root directory. 
For example:
`href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/demo/assets/css/style.css"`
`href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/demo/contents/test.php"`

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This is used for **directly loading into the Page** onload:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/demo/assets/css/style.css"
```

And this:

```
<li> <a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/demo/contents/test.php"> HOME </a> </li>
```

Is for user-actions, so you **link a destination** the user should be able to reach when clicking on it.